# How to show map in winform not using GIS and Internet Map?

Tags: .net, winforms, polygon

I Want to create a simple windows form application in .NET to show some province and to visualize some data on it. For example visualization of average age of people in a province by changing the province color and a number on it and click on each province to show details.
I cannot use `GIS` or internet Map services. Is there any way to show some polygon for provinces or something else?

Comment: But it has to be `.NET`? Also, why can't you use `GIS` or some internet maps?

Comment: Because it is a simple application and want to be simple to install to.

Comment: Right, sorry I don't know `.NET`, but you can write simple stuff in anything. I've used this and found it super-easy: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/
There's also this which appears interesting:
http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used graphics to draw polygons for each province and with an algorithm detect the mouse is in polygon to do some codes.